# Работа с телом цикла

Tags: c++

```
{
    int massiv[1000],i;  
    int sum ;  
    double pr1=1,  
    randomize();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)  //Заполнение массива  
    {
        massiv[i] = -5 + rand() % 56;  
        printf (" %d;", massiv[i]);} //Выводятся все элементы массива

        for (int i =1000-1; i>0; i--)  
        {
            if (massiv[i]>=0)  
            {
                pr1=massiv[i]*pr1;  
                sum *= massiv[i];
            }  
            else  
                break;  
     }

     while (massiv[i]!=0);  
     printf ("Result:  %.0lf ", pr1);  
     getchar(); getchar();  
     return 0;
```

Где оператор `while`, не могу правильно написать тело цикла. Пишу сумму, выводит неправильные данные (работаю в Turbo C++).

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 999; (i >=0) && (massiv[i] >=0); sum += massiv[i--]);
printf ("Result:  %d\n", sum);
```

Comment: массив выдает,а сумму эл-ов нет. у меня,видимо,еще и в коде ошибки :(
Условие задачи: . Дан одномерный массив из 1000 элементов, состоящий из случайных целых чисел в диапазоне от -5 до 50. Найти сумму элементов массива, с конца массива, до первого отрицательного элемента.

Comment: 1. Заполняете массив. Делаете это Вы вроде правильно. Далее ваш код откидываете.
2. Считаете требуемую сумму так, как я написал.
3. Сдаете код преподавателю.

Comment: Сдаете код преподавателю. И получаете пару и наряд вне очереди. На первом же отрицательном элементе вычисление суммы прекратится.

Comment: Смотри условия задачи.

Comment: @smthelse, уточните, до первого отрицательного элемента - первого с начала или первого с конца?

Comment: @mikillskegg. Да, пожалуй, Вы правы. Пардон. Но там еще и произведение вычисляют.

Comment: mikillskegg , с конца

Comment: про произведение в условиях ничего не сказано. Почему оно появляется в приведенном тексте, не знаю